# Laravel vue axios explanation needed

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to understand `Vue` and it's dependencies (newbie) just need help to understand the way axios works so it can be clear to me.

If I use code below it works to returning my data:

```
methods: {
            load: function() {
                axios.get('/api/projects')
                .then(
                    response => {
                        this.projects =  (response.data.projects);
                    }     
                )
                .catch(function (error) {
                    this.errors.push(error);
                    console.log(error);
                })
            }
        }
```

But if I use code below it doesn't return data:

```
methods: {
            load: function() {
                axios.get('/api/projects')
                .then(function (response) {
                    this.projects =  (response.data.projects);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    this.errors.push(error);
                    console.log(error);
                })
            }
        }
```

The difference is in `.then` part only.

Comment: Check the debug console of your web browser, I think you are under CORS issue https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Don't debug anything, everything works as expected. Just google for "arrow functions" and read on MDN whats the differences between arrow and normal functions. And focus on `this`, `context`.

Comment: @jesugmz thank you......

Comment: @VladislavLadicky thank you......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is referring to different object in both functions. 
Write `console.log(this)` and you will see that the one in arrow function is referring to Vue instance. The other one, however, is referring to other object. probably `window`. In the case of `function() {}` you can't access Vue instance via `this`. You need to store it beforehand in a variable.

```
var vm = this;
axios.get('/api/projects')
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(this); // undefined or other object
                console.log(vm); // vue instance
                vm.projects =  (response.data.projects);
            })
```

See another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this):

> An arrow function does not have its own this; the this value of the enclosing execution context is used.

It's not the axios that needs to be explained. It's how `this` keyword behaves in different contexts. Your first method makes use of something called Arrow Function, which doesn't have this of it's own so it uses the `this` of the current context. But your second method does have it's own this.

So, in order for you second method to work, you would have to cache `this` outside of the closure, like this:

```
methods: {
            load: function() {
                var that = this;
                axios.get('/api/projects')
                .then(function (response) {
                    that.projects =  (response.data.projects);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    this.errors.push(error);
                    console.log(error);
                })
            }
        }
```

And then it will work.